# unable to properly read data from httpclient json request angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created an Angular function in typescript that makes an http request for JSON data, and saves it to an object. The connection and parse of the data works fine, but i have to click the associated button twice to get the function to work properly.

**Code for function:**

```
test: any;
    callData(){
             this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?keyword=the&source=1&format=json')
                .subscribe(data => {this.test = data});
                //.subscribe(data => {this.new_test.push(data)});

               for (let i of this.test){
                    console.log(i['id'], i['title'], i['description'])
                }    
            }
```

Initially when I click the corresponding button to trigger the function, I see:
[image]

But once the button is clicked again, it seems that everything works fine.[image]

I think it has to do with the datatype being used, but I am trying to use a data structure that would allow me to save all of the elements being returned for the GET request so that I can then `console.log()` for now all of the different elements.

Comment: What have you got in your AboutComponent line 152 ?

Comment: @JulienMetral The for loop is there, which i put above

Comment: It's because this.test is undefined by default and will be populated before the request.

Comment: @JulienMetral that is what I thought was happening. Is there a way around that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for loop` is outside the subscription, so it gets executed in the sequence even before data get available through `subscription` that's why it gives error 1st time and next time when data is available it works.

when data gets available only you need to do the data manupulation. simple put your loop inside the subscription after assigning the `data` to `this.test`

```
test: any;
    callData(){
             this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?keyword=the&source=1&format=json')
                .subscribe(data => 
                      {
                         this.test = data;
                         for (let i of this.test){
                          console.log(i['id'], i['title'], i['description'])
                         } 
                      });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing for-loop and do console.log(this.test) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
callData(){
    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?keyword=the&source=1&format=json')
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.test = data // now test is populated
        for (let i of this.test){
            console.log(i['id'], i['title'], i['description'])
        }
    });
    // test here is undefined because the request is not launched
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the data asynchronously ,for loop start working before even you get data hence nothing is printed on the screen.

Next time when you click on the button http request has got completed and it print the data on the console.

```
   test: any;
        callData(){
                 this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?keyword=the&source=1&format=json')
                    .subscribe(data => {this.test = data});
                    //.subscribe(data => {this.new_test.push(data)

                    for (let i of this.test){
                        console.log(i['id'], i['title'], i['description'])
                    }

                  });


                }
```

Comment: I thought that was the case, I didn't realize that in Angular the code is not processed in a specific order. What would you recommend for this, or is there another data type that can be used?

Comment: It is not beacuse of the data type , it is beacuse of the asynchronous response , you need to define your code inside subscribe method only or return the Observable to component . If your are asking how to map the response to some object which has property id, title and description then you can create an interface and do like  ```this.http.get<InterfaceName>('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?keyword=the&source=1&format=json'``` , then it will automatically map your response